# Count elements in a list python

Tags: python, list

I need to be able to count how many of the string "O" is in my list

```
top_board = [
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
]
```

after I add elements like "O" and "X" it will look like this

```
top_board = [
    ["O", None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, "O", None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, "O", None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, "O", None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
]
```

now I need a function that checks if there is 0 of the "O" in my list and if there is then print something

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Just check if there is no "O"  in any of the list of top_board? or if is there is no "O" for each list? ie `sum([lst.count('O') for lst in top_board])` or `[sum(1 for j in i if j=="O") for i in top_board]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count_O(l):
    count = 0
    for sublist in l:
        count += sublist.count("O")
    return count


if count_O(top_board) == 0:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cnt = sum([lst.count('O') for lst in top_board])
# then do something depending on cnt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sum(x.count("O") for x in top_board)
```

Comment: `top_board.count("O")`?

Comment: Also, `sum([x for x in l])` runs (not significantly but visibly) faster than `sum(x for x in l)`. (at least on my machines) :P

Comment: Yeah probably because of  the recursive call of count ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
sum([sum([1 for x in y if x == "O"]) for y in top_board])
```

(hadn't notice the nesting...)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [j for i in top_board for j in i].count('O'):
    print "O is present in the list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a function:

```
def count_O (top_board):
    if True in ["O" in e for e in top_board]:
        print "O found"
```